# R - splitting a vector into three groups, min size, order matters

Tags: permutation, combinations, minimum

Hello everyone and thank you in advance for your time.

I am looking for the different combinations that could split a vector into three groups (high, medium, low), each group needs to contain at least three numbers, they should be ordered, and I'd like all the different ways this is possible.

For example; a seq of 1:10, by eye I count three ways of doing this

[image: splitting a seq of 1:10 min size of 3]

The output in any form I'd like would be something like this;

[image: These are the combinations splits with min 3]

Thank you again for your time and I apologize in advance if I'm confusing combination with permutation.

Tim

Answer (score 0):

So after hitting my head against this for awhile this is what I've come up with. It produces the max of the "low" and the min of the "high", I will just define "medium" by whats in the middle of those.

Thanks again for your time!!
_Tim

```
min_perm <- function(d) { # this function defines all the perms that have min 3 obs in each group
require(gtools) #for combinations

tt = combinations(3, d, repeats.allowed=T) #generate all the perms for three groups

dd = NULL # create an empty vector to hold perms that have at least three in each group
for (i in 1:dim(tt)[1]){
if(length(which(tt[i,] == 1))>=3 & 
     length(which(tt[i,] == 2))>=3 & 
     length(which(tt[i,] == 3))>=3){
  dd = rbind(dd,tt[i,])
  }}

combos = NULL # only need to max of the lowest and min of the highest group, the rest is medium group
for (i in 1:dim(dd)[1]){
combos = rbind(combos,c(max(which(dd[i,] ==1)),min(which(dd[i,] ==3))))}
colnames(combos) = c("low_max","high_min")
return(combos)
}
```